# Want to show data onMouseDown event in my REACT app

Tags: reactjs, popupwindow, onmousedown

I have a console.log showing the correct information `onMouseDown` event in my REACT app, how do I change it so it shows the data in a pop up window?

I am happy to use Modal or hover over event, whatever it takes to display the data. Data Consists of:

```
on item click   

{id: 3, group: 1, title: "resiting", bgColor: "#ff9800", start_time: Moment, …}
bgColor: "#ff9800"
end_time: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2018-10-11T15:08:00", _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
group: 1
id: 3
start_time: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2018-10-11T10:29:00", _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
title: "resiting"
__proto__: Object


import React, { Component } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import Timeline from "react-calendar-timeline";
import generateFakeData from "../../generate-fake-data";

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

const { groups, items } = generateFakeData();
const defaultTimeStart = moment()
  .startOf("day")
  .toDate();
const defaultTimeEnd = moment()
  .startOf("day")
  .add(1, "day")
  .toDate();

this.state = {
  groups,
  items,
  defaultTimeStart,
  defaultTimeEnd
};
     }

    itemRenderer = ({
    item,
    timelineContext,
    itemContext,
    getItemProps,
    getResizeProps
    }) => {
    const { left: leftResizeProps, right: rightResizeProps } = getResizeProps();
const backgroundColor = itemContext.selected
  ? itemContext.dragging
    ? "red"
    : item.selectedBgColor
  : item.bgColor;
return (
  <div
    {...getItemProps({
      style: {
        backgroundColor,
        color: "#ffffff",
        borderColor: "none",
        borderStyle: "none",
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 0,
        borderLeftWidth: itemContext.selected ? 1 : 1,
        borderRightWidth: itemContext.selected ? 1 : 1
      },
      onMouseDown: () => {
        console.log("on item click", item);
      }
    })}
  >
    {itemContext.useResizeHandle ? <div {...leftResizeProps} /> : null}

    <div
      style={{
        height: itemContext.dimensions.height,
        overflow: "hidden",
        paddingLeft: 3,
        textOverflow: "ellipsis",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap"
      }}
    >
      {itemContext.title}
    </div>

            {itemContext.useResizeHandle ? <div {...rightResizeProps} /> : null}
          </div>
        );
      };

      render() {
        const { groups, items, defaultTimeStart, defaultTimeEnd } = this.state;

        return (
          <Timeline
            groups={groups}
            items={items}
            sidebarContent={<div>Vehicle</div>}
            sidebarWidth={60}
            lineHeight={20}
            headerLabelGroupHeight={20}
            fullUpdate={false}
            itemsSorted
            itemTouchSendsClick={false}
            stackItems
            itemHeightRatio={0.98}
            showCursorLine
            canMove={true}
            canResize={true}
            defaultTimeStart={defaultTimeStart}
            defaultTimeEnd={defaultTimeEnd}
            itemRenderer={this.itemRenderer}
          />
        );
      }
    }
```

You can find it here on https://still-river-97856.herokuapp.com/tracking

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, you can use a [ant design modal](https://ant.design/components/modal/) or a [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) for the Modal(data={item}). But the logic is that once you click ok/away on the modal the clickedItem is set to null so that the modal is not displayed anymore.
Take a look at this code,

```
onMouseDown: () => {
        console.log("on item click", item);
        this.setState({clickedItem: item});
      }

onModalOkClick = () => {
     this.setState({clickedItem: null})
     }

 render() {
    const { groups, items, defaultTimeStart, defaultTimeEnd, clickedItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
      <Timeline
        groups={groups}
        items={items}
        sidebarContent={<div>Vehicle</div>}
        sidebarWidth={60}
        lineHeight={20}
        headerLabelGroupHeight={20}
        fullUpdate={false}
        itemsSorted
        itemTouchSendsClick={false}
        stackItems
        itemHeightRatio={0.98}
        showCursorLine
        canMove={true}
        canResize={true}
        defaultTimeStart={defaultTimeStart}
        defaultTimeEnd={defaultTimeEnd}
        itemRenderer={this.itemRenderer}
      />
     {clickedItem ? <Modal data={clickedItem}> : null}
   </div>
    );
  }
```

Let me know if you need help with the modal or you are still unsure how to proceed. 
The dashboard looks nice btw. :)

Comment: Hi @Shivam Gupta, thank for your answer. I tried to implement your suggestion and updated my code:
https://github.com/MartaDS/TranslabDashbard/blob/latest/src/views/Tracking/CustomTimeline.jsx

but still nothing is happening when I click on the item, am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @MartaDyer-Smith you forgot a few things 
1. add the this.setState({clickedItem: item}); in the onMouseDown()
2. I don't see any modal to display the data

Could you tell me how you are displaying, because the clicked item is available in the console

Comment: Hi @Shivam Gupta, I changed to:
onMouseDown: () => {this.setState({clickedItem: null});}
but still nothing. The Modal should display data from this file: https://github.com/MartaDS/TranslabDashbard/blob/latest/src/generate-fake-data.js

Comment: Thank you @Shivam Gupta, I have done that. How do I get the Modal with data to show up now? I click on the item and no modal shows....

Comment: Try something like this, you can use a ant design modal or a react-modal for the Modal

Comment: Hi @Shivam Gupta, thank you so much for all your advice so far. I added react modal as well as ant design modal, but I just can't get it to work...I spent hours on this and reached a point where I'm just banging my head against the wall. Could you show me how do do it in code?

Comment: Sure. Can you share a codepen with your latest code and I'll show it in there.